# edittext cursor and the editing area not showing

Tags: android, android-edittext

My edit text shows hint but it does not show the cursor and the area for typing.what should i do so that it shows the cursor and the area and not just the hint?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/numberborder"
tools:context="com.example.light.primenumbercompanion.MainMenu">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checker"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:text="@string/checker"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkerQeustion"
        android:layout_below="@id/checker"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/checkerQuestion"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkerInput"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkerQeustion"
        android:hint="@string/checkerInput"
        android:inputType="number"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

i feel like the user will not know where to input the number

Comment: There's nothing wrong I found here. I can see both cursor and default edittext underline border. Can you add a screenshot? It might be `@drawable/numberborder` causing a background which is confusing with default edittext background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in your activity copy my code i've run your code it works fine although you were not closing scroll view close it first or maybe u forget to send code of closing scroll view and send your java so i'd verify it so there is no problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main_menu"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checker"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:text="Heading text"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkerQeustion"
        android:layout_below="@id/checker"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="textview"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/checkerInput"
        android:layout_below="@id/checkerQeustion"
        android:hint="testedittext"
        android:inputType="number"/>


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the colour of the cursor in your *EditText* you can add the below line in your *EditText* tag in XML

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_color"
```

> cursor_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="3dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

My default colour is black you can change the colour whatever you want.
Try it an let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: ya that's a possibility that maybe your cursor color is same as background that is "white" so it won't show there. @sina rafiei